# How to make WebView inside ConstraintView respect bounds?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout. Basically, a top and bottom text views with webview in between to fill the remaining space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="24dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heading"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/disclaimer"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To load the url I am doing,

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

    WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        webViewSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.icons101.com/icons/21/Circle_by_Martz90/128/games.png");
```

I expected the webview to expand to fill the entire screen even when content is small but this is what I get

[image]

How do fix the "disclaimer" to the bottom of the parent and let webview fill the remaining white space?

Answer (score 3):

**You can use this layout:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="24dp"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="heading"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="disclaimer"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/disclaimer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heading" />
```

Your code was really almost 100% good, but your webView was centered to the center of the screen so I constraints it to its bounds and now it will take all the remaining space.